# Trying to delete rows with NAs, so that I can do chi-square analysis

Tags: r, na, chi-squared, rowdeleting

R community.

I am trying to delete the rows **TEMPORARILY** that have NA, so that I may conduct a chi-square analysis on my data. Otherwise, there would be a column titled "unknown" when I choose two variable to make a data table, and that would interfere with the chi-square analysis from what I know.

The rows correspond to each patient in the data.
mint$bp_type2 and mint$menopause are two columns.
My thought was to replace the NAs with a random number; I chose 20. That way, I would be able to delete these rows that had a value of 20 under that column.

Here is the code:

```
mint <- mint[!(mint$bp_type2 == 20),]
mint$menopause[is.na(mint$menopause)] <- 20
mint <- mint[!(mint$menopause == 20),]
table(mint$bp_type2,mint$menopause)
chisq.test(mint$bp_type2,mint$menopause)
```

This is my error message:

```
> mint$bp_type2[is.na(mint$bp_type2)] <- 20
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(mint$bp_type2), value = c(1L, 4L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Subsequently, I run the rest of the code, and I see that the data set has not eliminated these rows, since the data table generated still has a column labeled "unknown."

Please let me know what I can do to fix this, so that I can do my chi-square analysis without an "unknown" column.

Thank you!!

Comment: you could remove `NA` columns by using `na.omit()`, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the value with 20 when you can remove it directly?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is because the column 'bp_type2' is a `factor` and '20' is not one of the `levels` of that column.  We can either convert to a `character` or create '20' as one of the `levels`

```
levels(mint$bp_type2) <- c(levels(mint$bp_type2), '20')
```

and then do the assignment

```
mint$bp_type2[is.na(mint$bp_type2)] <- '20'
```

---

With `forcats`, `fct_expand` can add more levels

```
library(forcats)
mint$bp_type2 <- fct_expand(mint$bp_type2, '20')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
chisq.test(na.omit(df$columnName))
```

This will omit the NAs while proeceding the Chi-Square Test.